# Ebay Api Sort the searched result based on watchcount of item

Tags: ebay-api

Ebay Api end point "findItemsAdvanced" and "findItemsByKeywords" return the searched items and has their sorting techniques but sortOrder "WatchCountDescending" is not applicable.

Also "getMostWatchedItems" returns the top Items based on watchcount in particular category but does not provide searching.

So, How can i sort the searched products based on watchCount on items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This currently doesn't appear possible in the eBay API.